# Melhores Cenário: Gravação em tabela de n para n Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Possuo algumas dúvidas quanto a gravação de registros em tabelas de N para M.

Meu cenário é o seguinte:[image: Cenário atual]

No meu banco ao inserir um médico insiro na tabela "Médico" o cadastro de Médico,
e em "Médico x Especialidade" as especialidades deste médico.
Alteração de registro:

**Solução 1** - Em um cenário normal, eu daria update na tabela "Medico" e após isso eu escolheria a exclusão de todos os registros de "Médico x Especialidade" e em seguida faria o insert de toda a lista de "Médico x Especialidade".

Como estou aplicando o Hibernate no projeto e tive pouco contato com ele, pedi ajuda para um colega de trabalho.
O mesmo disse que esta minha "solução" estaria muito errada. Pois iterar sobre cada item teria um custo menor do que iterar sobre trabalhar com a lista inteira. A solução dele seria a seguinte:

**Solução 2** - Preencho uma lista auxiliar com minhas especialidades já cadastradas no banco de dados (normalmente isso é feito na pesquisa do registro, então isso eu já faço de todo jeito). Na alteração eu percorreria TODA a lista e verificaria cada item. Se o item foi excluído, eu iria fazer a exclusão no banco de dados. Se o item foi inserido, eu iria faze o insert no banco de dados, se o item permanece na tela, eu não executaria nada.

**Observação sobre a Solução 1**: Ao meu ver (que pode estar equivocado) a solução 1 seria a ideal, pois eu realizaria todos os passos em uma unica conexão e para uma lista muito grande economizaria muito tempo e memória.

**Observação sobre a Solução 2**: O colega que me aconselhou disse que eu utilizaria muito recurso da memória utilizando uma conexão para trabalhar com toda a lista (????) porém tenho muitas dúvidas. O pró é para lista pequena, mas mesmo assim vejo muitas idas e voltas no banco de dados e ao meu ver isso é ruim. Como estou trabalhando com Hibernate e tenho pouco conhecimento, estou com bastante duvidas sobre o que usar.

O que já tinha pensado era caso haja alteração na lista, eu faria a exclusão e inseriria novamente os registros.
Neste cenário qual seria a melhor prática?

---

Comparar as especialidades novas com as antigas eu teria que iterar sobre toda a lista e em seguida fazer a inserção e exclusão.

Mesmo que a entrada e saida no banco de dados seja feita em apenas um comando (DELETE IN) a iteração sobre a lista fica totalmente refém do tamanho da minha entrada (Logicamente). Em uma entrada de 10 especialidades é Ok. Porém em uma entrada maior a complexidade é exponencial.

Bom, no que me lembro sobre complexidade de algoritmos isso demandaria de muito tempo e memória. Porém meu amigo diz que isso é desprezível. Ai eis minha duvida. Pensando que não sei qual será a dimensão da minha tabela de especialidades, qual a melhor forma de implementar...

Answer (score 0):

Bom se entendi bem o seu caso, com base em experiências parecidas, você poderia montar assim:
Em uma atualização de médico e suas respectivas especialidades, você pode fazer um algoritmo de comparação das novas especialidades com a antigas:

> mantém das antigas especialidades o que não foram excluídas dentre as novas;
>
> excluí das antigas o que não tem nas novas; e
>
> adiciona as especialidades novas que não tinha dentre as antigas.

Entende? Assim você não precisa excluir todas e reinserir tudo. Outra observação, seria retirar o `id` da tabela `medicoXespecialidade`, pois você pode fazer uma chave primária conjunta de id_Medico e id_Especialidade.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá Maycon, como minha resposta ficou grande postei abaixo!

Comment: Entendo sua preocupação, minha resposta é no mesmo sentindo do seu amigo, a qual acredito ser a melhor, pois o custo de comparação será menor que o de comunicação e modificação no banco de dados.

Comment: Mas vc não precisa fazer várias comunicações ao banco para a aplicação necessitar de muita memória. Basta percorrer um laço um número alto de vezes que ela necessita. É isso que quis dizer. Independente da comunicação ao banco, ou se esta faz diferença com o hibernate, qual seria a melhor solução.